# Styling the body element in svelte

Tags: css, svelte, vite, darkmode

My goal is to make a darkmode for my web app.
To get my setup enter `npm init vite` and pick svelte as a framwork. Then follow the command line instructions. Go to src > App.svelte:

Try the following:

```css
body {
    background: black;
}
```

You will get the following warning by the svelte extension in vs-code:

```
Unused CSS selector "body"
```

[image: Image of my css and the warning]

To check if this error is related to the browser I manually set the property in chrome dev tools and the expected result was achieved.

[image: Image of the same css working in dev tools]

Because of this I have the following questions:

- Why doesn't svelte allow styling of the body in this way?
- How can you style the body tag in svelte?
- How would darkmode be implemented?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Why doesn't svelte allow styling of the body in this way?

Because svelte styles are **scoped by default**. You have to explicitly tell svelte that you want to apply a style globally.

> How can you style the body tag in svelte?

You want to use the css selector `:global(body)` instead of `body`.

> How would darkmode be implemented?

In the similar way you style `:global(body)`, using the `:global(body.dark-mode)` selector.
[Here is an example.](https://svelte.dev/repl/ed4fef4beceb4b0eb295d1f9fdf3bd62?version=3.6.9)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what I tried to do by adding a `global.css` file to your project and importing it to your file like this:

```html
<script>
  import "./global.css";
</script>
```

If you really want it to be global you can also link it in your index.html in the root of your project like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```